# Why doesnt frame show up with its title?

Tags: java, jframe

i have created FlowLayoutEx with some operations.then tried to put them into frame in standart way.

```
public static void main(String args[]){

    FlowLayoutEx applet=new FlowLayoutEx();
    JFrame frame=new JFrame("HW2LayoutSettings");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.add(applet,BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
    applet.init();
    applet.start();
    frame.setSize(400,300);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);

}
```

Comment: What is a `FlowLayoutEx`?

Comment: Is it really the window (JFrame) that isn't appearing?  Or just the content inside it?  If so, is it because the JFrame is really small?  Or because the content panel doesn't render (e.g. is all white, or similar)?

Answer (score 0):

It probably does show up, but maybe it's too small or an Exception was thrown before, it's impossible to know without knowing what your `FlowLayoutEx` class is.

But when you call `pack()` you set the window to a size corresponding to the preferred size of its components. It means:

1. Your previous call to `setSize` is useless since the size is set again by the call to `pack`
2. Your custom component should be set a preferred size.

Answer (score 0):

What is the preferred size (re getPreferredSize()) of *applet*?  Could it be (0, 0)?  Is the JFrame using a BorderLayout?  I think that is the default, but I'm not sure.  Try setting it yourself: frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout()).  Not sure about BorderLayout.PAGE_END - I always use BorderLayout.CENTER (for the main, or only, component in a JFrame).